# AngularJS v1.5.0 ng-model doesn't work after image upload and conversion to base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I try to upload images as base64 in a Canvas application with angular v1.5

```html
<body ng-app="ThermalLabelWebEditor" ng-controller="Controller as main">
......
<label class="col-md-12">
Base64
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" accept="image/jpeg" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="main.uploadImage()">Add Image</button>
<textarea id="vf_base64" required class="form-control" 
          ng-model="main.imageItem.source_base64">
</textarea>

</label>
```

The upload function

```
var controller = app.controller("Controller", function ($http,$scope) {
    ........
    this.imageItem = {};

    this.uploadImage = function () {

        var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
            r = new FileReader();

        r.readAsDataURL(f);                
        var me = this;
        r.onloadend = function () {

            var res = r.result.substring(23, r.result.length);                           
            me.imageItem.source_base64 = res;  

            console.log(me.imageItem);  
        };
        r.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            me.imageItem.source_base64 =  'Error: ' + error;
        };
    };
```

I see that the field is filled

```
{data_field: "", data_field_format_string: "", comments: "", print_as_graphic: false, x: 0.10431385040283203, …}
data_field: ""
....
source_base64: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUUExMWFh"
sizing: 1
width: 2.7291666666666665
height: 2.5625
name_at_printer_storage: ""
```

But nothing appears in the Textarea

Answer (score 0):

Add [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
this.uploadImage = function () {

    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

    r.readAsDataURL(f);                
    var me = this;
    r.onloadend = function () {

        var res = r.result.substring(23, r.result.length);                           
        me.imageItem.source_base64 = res;  
        //IMPORTANT
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log(me.imageItem);  
    };
    r.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        me.imageItem.source_base64 =  'Error: ' + error;
        //IMPORTANT
        $scope.$apply();
    };
};
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You can also use $apply() to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript.

Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to $apply is **needed only when implementing custom event callbacks,** or when working with third-party library callbacks.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: But the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with a directive.
The code:

```
app.directive("ngImageread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngImageread: "=",
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.ngImageread = loadEvent.target.result.substring(23, reader.result.length);
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```